# Check if Adsense GDPR consent message has been accepted or not

Tags: javascript, cookies, adsense

How can I understand if a user has accepted the Adsense GDPR consent or not?

I used this code but it doesn't work as I would like because it starts as soon as the page is loaded:

```
if (!adsbygoogle.loaded) {
  console.log('hi');
}
```